# Is it possible to terminate a TCPClient immediately?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, indy10

My app sends data to a Server using a TidTCPClient. The Server uses a TidTCPServer. All works fine and I am now trying to handle unexpected situations.

When I disconnect the network cable between server and client, and then try to close the client, it waits for a long time, until it finally closes:

```
TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
TCPClient.Disconnect;
TCPClient.Free;
```

TCPClient.Free is the place where it waits. This is sometimes 30 seconds, sometimes even longer.

Is there a way to terminate a TCPClient immediately, no matter what it is doing at that moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be clearing the `InputBuffer` after calling `Disconnect()`, not before.

In any case, there is no reason for a socket to cause such a hang when disconnecting/freeing the `TIdTCPClient`, unless you have messed around with the socket's LINGER options.  So I have to suspect your own code is at fault first.  Which version of Indy are you using?  Do you have any event handlers assigned to the `TIdTCPClient`?  Have you tried stepping through TIdTCPClient's destructor in the debugger to see what is really happening?

Answer (score 0):

It probably waits for a timeout. Look at the properties of the component to lower the timeout value

Comment: There is no timeout for disconnecting.